# Can Core Data Become Corrupted?

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Recently I implemented a new object type to be stored in Core Data. A very simply object: "LikedObjects" with one data type called 
"likedObjects". Here is a snippet from my Xcode project.

[image]

---

For whatever reason, saving the data did not work. It would ALWAYS return nil (when before implementing this it worked perfectly for the other, crossed-out entities).

**SOLUTION:**

I deleted and re-installed the app. Works fine. Changed 0 code.

**My question**:

> Is it possible / a way for `CoreData` to corrupt? I want to know a potential reason for *why* deleting and reinstalling the app was a solution, so that if so I can prevent this in any way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. One of the reasons could be a line separator coming from a Windows app (CRLF) or an otherwise invisible character within the XCode editor, coming from copy & paste.

One way to get rid of these problems is moving the file outside the project and then add it as an existing file once again. The import/copy function does a decent job of cleaning unwanted code. If this does not help, then you will have to write a function which purges ASCII characters 0-26, exception made for code 11 (LF). If you have binary data though, it may not work!

Finally, a matching pair of keys and values may have gone havoc. There, you will have to paste one by one (pair), until you find the cause of grief.

Comment: That’s why delete reinstall worked. Hopefully it won’t happen with the final build - thanks

Comment: I’m still confused - is there something in my code I could have done to cause this? Or is it simply a random failure

Comment: It happened to me after pasting text from a web page into a string field, and in various occasions just by itself.

Comment: Sounds reliable. Is there a way to avoid this? Or a better alternative native to iOS

Comment: I attempted to use SQLite instead, but then I had to fix the native code by wrapper functions, because it was made available in 2001 and until then a lot of bugs were fixed ... not in iOS though. However, it was one of the better choices I made :-)